# Jquery UI dialog in place of javascript confirm

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, confirm

I have a bunch of validation javascript processes with confirms. I want to use jquery ui dialog, but I need to return true for the rest of the validation processes.

For example:

```
var where_to_coupon = confirm(pm_info_msg_013);
      if (where_to_coupon== true) {
      doSubmit=true;
      return doSubmit;
```

So I need a function to replace confirm with a UI dialog, pull the message string (pm_info_msg_013), and use my own buttons or UI buttons to return true for the validation process.

Not sure where to start with this one.

help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In jQuery UI dialog, set the `modal` option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the `buttons` option.

```
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: pm_info_msg_013,
            click : function() {    
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                // code related to "where_to_coupon== true" goes here
                // submit form
                }
            }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                doSubmit = false;
                // don't submit form
            }}]
    });
```

See the demo here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

**Update:**
This will allow you to create multiple confirms. Usage:

```
function CreateDialog(okText, cancelText, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: [{
                text: okText,
                click : function() {    
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    okCallback();
                    }
                }, {
                text: cancelText,
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    cancelCallback();
                }}]
            }
        });

// ******* usage #1 ********    
CreateDialog(pm_info_msg_013, "Cancel", function () {
   // where_to_coupon== true
}, function() {

   // where_to_coupon== false
});

function OnConfirmTrue() {
  // do something
}

function OnConfirmFalse() {
  // do something
}

// ******* usage #2 ********

CreateDialog(pm_info_msg_013, "Cancel", OnConfirmTrue, OnConfirmFalse);
```

Comment: not sure how to incorporate with my javascript confirm string

Comment: You would need to dynamically change the html of the `dialog-confirm` div (`$("#dialog-confirm").html(pm_info_msg_013)`) before calling the above code

Comment: ok, thanks for that. Next question being how to trigger a "if (where_to_coupon== true) {"

Comment: @Jason: Put them inside the respective `click` functions. You can call other functions on your page from there too. You don't need to check for `where_to_coupon== true` as the handlers get called based on what button was clicked. See my update again.

Comment: but doesn't that only return the text: pm_info_msg_013, versus the string the pm_info_msg_013 references?

Comment: `text: pm_info_msg_013` will assign the value of `pm_info_msg_013`, not the verbatim "pm_info_msg_013".

Comment: thanks for all of your help, but I see another issue. I have several confirms and each has a different action on the return true. I'm not sure I see a way around that here...

Comment: what if I used my own buttons within the error message, instead of using jquery UI's buttons? Would I be able to return a true value to the javascript validation?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a plugin for jQuery UI, called dialogWrapper, that provides several methods, including a confirm method. You call it like this:

```
$.confirm("Prompt", function(){}, function(){}, {});
```

The second and third arguments are what to do when the yes and no button are clicked, respectively. The fourth is for additional arguments.

Check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/dialogwrapper/

It doesn't work like the native JavaScript `confirm` method, though, since it is asynchronous. So you wouldn't be able to directly overwrite `confirm` with `$.confirm`.

Comment: looks interesting, but I'm trying to touch minimal code (especially in the javascript) - so how would I return true or false within your plugin?

Comment: You can't, since `$.confirm` works asynchronously. It relies entirely on callbacks. There is no way to use jQuery Dialogs synchronously without ugly, UI-blocking code (for example, a `while` loop that checks if a button has been pressed yet).

Comment: well, I assume there's gotta be a way (a second function) or an onclick event to trigger a true?

Comment: what if I used my own buttons within the error message, instead of using jquery UI's buttons?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Impromtu by Trent Richardson?

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

This jquery plug-in can give you the control you are looking for with prompts and confirms and more.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**