# Can I use confirm() while uplifting my script from javascript to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

Can I use confirm() while uplifting my script from javascript to jquery? I have tried to use dialog in jQuery but i need to get the alert box in same style as in confirm()(java script). Is there a way to get it or can I use confirm() in the Jquery????

Thanks in advance..,

Comment: try to post codes otherwise this question will be closed.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript, its not a separate entity, you can use `confirm()` in exactly the same way you would had you not been using jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015499/jquery-ui-dialog-in-place-of-javascript-confirm        please find modal dialog box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### jQuery is a JavaScript library.

*It is **NOT** a different programming language.* You can easiliy use `confirm` or any other native JavaScript functions when you use jQuery.

Comment: +1 just for the huge heading. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a library of utility functions written in, and used from, JavaScript. There's no reason you can't use `confirm` in your code, whether or not you use jQuery.

`confirm` provides a poor user experience, can't be styled, and offers zero validation functionality, but there's nothing about jQuery that prevents your using it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use confirm in JQuery. JQuery is built on JavaScript it is not a replacement for JavaScript. All JavaScript functions work in JQuery.